# remove strange file extensions

Tags: file, batch-file

I have a folder which contains some files with names as given below

```
0003.4b3d943b8df71af248d12f8b2e7a224a
0004.1874ab60c71f0b31b580f313a3f6e777
0005.1f42bb885de0ef7fc5cd09d34dc2ba54
0006.7a32642f8c22bbeb85d6c3b5f3890a2c
0007.859c901719011d56f8b652ea071c1f8b
.
.
.
```

I want to rename these files by removing these extensions and need only `file name` part ie.

```
0003
0004
0005
0006
.
.
.
.
```

How to achieve this using a script?

Comment: What kind of script ??

Comment: your folder contains **some** of this files, and the other?

Comment: all files have different extension of same length as described above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all the files in the folder are to be renamed, then all you need is:

```
ren * *.
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for more info.

If there are also files in the folder that should not be renamed (files with "normal" extensions), then the following will work:

```
for /f "eol=; delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d *^|findstr /r "\.................................$"') do @ren "%%F" *.
```

The `\.` matches the dot, and the 32 `.` match the 32 characters of the extension. The `$` anchors the regex match to the end of the line.

Change each `%%F` to `%F` if you want to run the command directly from the command prompt instead of from within a batch script.

Answer (score 3):

The line you are looking for is

```
for %%I in (d:\temp\*) DO ren "%%I" "%%~nI"
```

Where `d:\temp` is the location of the files you want to rename. Note that your batch file has to be in a different folder, else you will rename it as well. Also note that this will rename **all** the files in the target folder.

Comment: @mohit - See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16965749/1012053) for a much simpler way to drop the extension from all files in a folder. Although I wouldn't recommend Laf's answer, I don't understand the down vote.

Comment: @dbenham True, your solution is way simpler ;) I don't get the downvote either, I would have appreciated a comment explaining why.

Comment: me too do not understand the down vote. it just worked for me that's why i accepted it.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a-d /b') do echo ren "%%~fi" "%%~ni"
```

look at the output and remove the `echo`, if it is OK.

Answer (score -1):

Use something like this

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /a:-d /b /o:n') do echo %%~nA
```